# Letter in LaTeX

Tags: letters

How to create a letter with the following structure (A4 paper)?

I'm novice to using LaTeX for letters!

Top Right - Date.

Top Left - From

---------- To

---------- Through

---------- Opening

---------- Subject

---------- Content

---------- Closing (Right)

Comment: Best is to use one of the letter classes. `letter` is one. http://ctan.org/topic/letter includes a variety of other possibilities.

Comment: When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: You can use the `letter` class or the [scrlttr2](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) from the KOMA Script bundle.

Take a look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters)